# VLOOKUP not working with identical values

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hi I have a column of some created code blocks pasted with no line breaks or spaces etc.

```
<divclass='related-search'><divclass='heading-new'><divclass='heading-new__title'>SeeRelatedSearches</div></div><divclass='related-search__list'><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/mens-white-shirts'>WhiteShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/double-cuff-shirts'>DoubleCuffShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/classic-fit'>ClassicFitShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/formal-shirts'>FormalShirts</a></div></div>
```

I've created another column in a second sheet using each unique value of this first column and assigning it a number.

```
<divclass='related-search'><divclass='heading-new'><divclass='heading-new__title'>SeeRelatedSearches</div></div><divclass='related-search__list'><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/mens-white-shirts'>WhiteShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/double-cuff-shirts'>DoubleCuffShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/classic-fit'>ClassicFitShirts</a><ahref='https://savilerowco.com/shirts/formal-shirts'>FormalShirts</a></div></div>
```

```
rsb_1
```

When using a vlookup to return the block number of the relevant code block it's giving me a #VALUE error.

```
=VLOOKUP(N2,'RSB NAME HELP'!A:D,4,0)
```

Comment: A clear layout of your data / example may help.

Comment: What's a block number?  Which cells are your data in?  What's in cells `D1` to `D4`? (since that's where it's looking for the response)....  What are you actually trying to do? (What data do you have, and what do you need from it?)

Comment: Apologies, [this is the code block column](https://gyazo.com/eabfc8f06b7a3505f9b99da4fc8a80f7) with the vlookup next to it, I'm trying to match it to [this column](https://gyazo.com/2b557424f0a0a4c60689f4b7972691c9) and return the 'BLOCK NAME VALUE' cell, both code blocks are the same, I have removed all spacing line breaks etc and still getting the error. However, [an IF function](https://gyazo.com/76ec37380a924bb8774f3ac440b522cd) does work.

Comment: [Some additional screenshots](https://gyazo.com/3fce4c04fcc41949285d3fba6948cbc6) just showing [the code blocks](https://gyazo.com/576c35921d1d03426fd50018ae26d7ee) do match, and also the [vlookup I'm using](https://gyazo.com/865b707685d8441d011d1de8d2bc4e80)

Comment: Can you share the file somehow? If it's something in the data, copying/pasting from your post won't allow us to reproduce the problem